# What could be wrong with my .zshrc for JUNIT5?

Tags: java, junit, environment-variables, zshrc

so I am trying to add JUnit5 on my macbook.
These are the steps I took in attempt to get it up and running.
First created a folder called Source in my user folder so imagine file path Users/"insertmynamehere"/Source this is where I placed my .jar file.
More specifically : junit-platform-console-standalone-1.9.0.jar

then, I ended up creating a .zshrc in the same folder that contains source with the following commands (modified slightly to not include my actual name on here:

```
export CLASSPATH="/Users/insermynamehere/Source/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.9.0.jar;."
export JUNIT5 ="/Users/insertmynamehere/Source/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.9.0.jar"
alias junit='java -jar $JUNIT5 -cp . --select-class'
alias javadoc='javadoc -tag custom.require:cm:"Precondition:" -tag custom.ensure:cm:ndition:" -Xdoclint:none *.java'
```

after opening a new terminal window, the first thing after last login is a zshrc:2(*indicating line 2*)[insert file path] not found.
I searched around online and my laptop is 2 months old, brand new, but i did some preliminary checks like seeing if my JRE is working properly and it is. At least according to the javac command I ran through terminal which popped up with usage details.
Im wondering if I am missing something or there is a formatting error perhaps? It passes the first line without saying anything, and I know the path is true.

Comment: I would never set a global CLASSPATH environment variable, this is quite misleading. Also the delimiter there is `:` not `;` (the latter only for Windows). If you use the junit jar file with the `-jar` parameter it's in the classpath anyways.

Comment: Not sure if rc files in random places is good either. If you're going to do that, you should source it from the one in your home directory